# Updating large volume of records

Tags: plsql, sql-update, multiple-columns, records, large-data-volumes

I have a table having more than 10 mil records and I have to update multiple columns of this table from the data which I get from few other tables which again have large number of records. All the tables are indexed

I tried doing it in batches and updating in concurrent sessions but it it taking very long time. Is there any alternative approach for this problem?

Comment: Check out this comment by John Bittner on AskTom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330

Comment: I did try one of the above approaches and as I multiple columns to be updated from different tables it is still taking very long time to create the table.

Comment: I find interesting that creating the table is taking a long time, that operation should be almost instant. Are you creating the table like this "create table xyz_HOLD as select * from xyz where rownum<1"? If so, are you then altering like this 'Alter tablexyz nologging'? Also, please note the hints that they're using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to build a brand new table(with nologging) and to parallelize.

1) First create your dummy hold table (with no rows):

```
create table xyz_HOLD as select * from xyz where rownum<1
```

Avoid logging all these operations*...

```
Alter table xyz_HOLD nologging
```

*With `nologging`, if the system aborts, you simply re-run the 'update' again, as you have the original data in the main table

2)

```
    insert /*+ append parallel (xyzhold,12) */ 
      into xyz_hold xyzhold (field1, field2, field3) 
    select /*+ parallel (x,12) */ xyz.field1, my_new_value_for_field2, xyz.field3 
      from xyz x 
     where blah blah blah
```

3) when done, either rename the table, or swap the partition if your original table is partitioned, and you only updated one partition as we do.

+) Obviously you also need to rebuild indecies, etc as required afterwards.